# SQL Server - The conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, type-conversion

I need to generate string with random digits with specified length so I do:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Generate Account]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @accountNumber VARCHAR(36)
    DECLARE @acc_1 BIGINT
    DECLARE @acc_2 BIGINT
    DECLARE @acc_3 BIGINT
    DECLARE @acc_4 BIGINT -- line 26
    DECLARE @acc_5 BIGINT
    DECLARE @acc_6 BIGINT

    SET @acc_1 = 1000000-ceiling(rand()*100000) + datepart(ms, getdate())
    SET @acc_2 = 1000000-ceiling(rand()*100000) + datepart(ms, getdate())
    SET @acc_3 = 1000000-ceiling(rand()*100000) + datepart(ms, getdate())
    SET @acc_4 = 1000000-ceiling(rand()*100000) + datepart(ms, getdate()) -- line 33
    SET @acc_5 = 1000000-ceiling(rand()*100000) + datepart(ms, getdate())
    SET @acc_6 = 1000000-ceiling(rand()*100000) + datepart(ms, getdate())

    SET @accountNumber = CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @acc_1) + 
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @acc_2) + 
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @acc_3) + 
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @acc_4) + 
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @acc_5) + 
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @acc_6)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[account] 
    (
        [identifier]
    ) VALUES (
        @accountNumber
    )

    RETURN @accountNumber
END
```

But I'm getting error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure Generate Account, Line 26 [Batch Start   Line 2]
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Generate Account, Line 33 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   The conversion of the varchar value '976547932115913127987338933646998655' overflowed an int column.
>   The 'Generate Account' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.

Why? I have already changed `@acc_X` from INT to BIGINT but I still getting this error...

Comment: I propose that your `identifier` column in the `account` table is either the wrong type or is not wide enough to hold the 36 digit value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Every column which holding this value is `VARCHAR(36)`

Comment: The problem is the target column for the insert.  Read the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is your:

```
RETURN @accountNumber
```

In SQL Server, a stored procedure can only return an `int` while you are trying to return a 36 digit `varchar`, and SQL Server is implicitly trying to convert that to an `int`.

If you need the inserted value replace that line with a simple select statement:

```
SELECT @accountNumber AS AccountNumber
```

or

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and it should work.

If you need other options to return / output a value from the stored procedure, take a look at:

[return data from a stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: by default a stored procedure returns the 1 if it was successful, you don't need to specify it unless you implement specific logic or exception handling. I assume he requires the generated account number as this is randomly generated.

Comment: @RaulSebastian, by default, stored procedures return 0 for success and non-zero on error. The best practice is to use the return code only to indicate success or failure rather than return data; data should be returned using output parameters or result sets.

Comment: you are right about the returning 0 by default, don't know why I had 1 in mind. As for the returning values, it's exactly what I advised in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to make `[dbo].[Generate Account]` a function instead of a procedure. As a function, you can specify the return type.